# Can't Return Derived Type With unique_ptr in C++

Tags: c++, stl, segmentation-fault, polymorphism, unique-ptr

I am getting a weird error. When I try to return a unique pointer to a derived type in a function that returns a unique pointer to the base type, it as though the return value gets demoted to the base type. I cannot access any of its methods or members, and the program segfaults if I try to.

The example below segfaults if I try to reassign e1 to to the return type and call its "eval" method. Strangely, calling the eval method before returning works properly. It seems to happen when I use the assigned variable as one of the arguments for the function, as creating a new object to store the return type does work.

Unfortunately, my algorithm requires a line like so:

```
e1 = create( *e1, *e2 );
```

See below for the full code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class expr
{
public:
    virtual int eval() = 0;
    virtual ~expr() = default;
};

class add_expr : public expr
{
    expr& e1;
    expr& e2;
public:
    add_expr( expr& e1, expr& e2 ): e1(e1), e2(e2) {}
    int eval(){ return e1.eval() + e2.eval(); }
};

class int_expr : public expr
{
    int value;
public:
    int_expr( int value ) : value(value) {}
    int eval(){ return value; }
};

std::unique_ptr<expr> create( expr& ast1, expr& ast2 );

int main()
{
    auto e1 = std::unique_ptr<expr>( new int_expr( 10 ) );
    auto e2 = std::unique_ptr<expr>( new int_expr( 10 ) );
    e1 = create( *e1, *e2 );

    // this seg faults
    std::cout << e1->eval() << '\n';

    // this works properly
    auto e3 = create( *e1, *e2 );
    e3->eval();
    return 0;
}

std::unique_ptr<expr> create( expr& ast1, expr& ast2 )
{
    auto r = std::unique_ptr<expr>( new add_expr( ast1, ast2 ) );

    // this works properly
    std::cout << r->eval() << '\n';
    return r;
}
```

Note: I know this example is ridiculous, it is simply a consolidated form of a very large program.

Comment: What do you expect?  Your call to `create` stored a reference to a value that was deleted before you used it.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
e1 = create( *e1, *e2 );
```

you reassign `e1`. That means the thing that `e1` used to point to (an `int_expr`) gets deleted (because it's a `unique_ptr`).

Now the new thing `e1` points to (an `add_expr`) still holds a reference to that `int_expr` that just got deleted. When it tries to use that reference to a deleted object, it encounters undefined behaviour, and in your case, a segfault.

Comment: Is there a solution that would still allow me to use e1?

 auto temp = create( *e1, *e2 );
 e1 = std::move( temp );

also segfaults, for example.